# Different Lighting, Same Settings

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I have two imported models, FBX (1) on the left and IFC (2) on the right.

I have the same lighting settings (same HDRI and same Sun lamp at the exact location and orientation) but I get a different lighting. In the FBX the lighting is darker[image: lighting].

I was wondering if the different file formats have influence over the lighting or if there is a different factor that influence the lighting?